# How to find the residue at $z_0=\exp(i\pi/3)$ of $f(z)=\frac{z^{2}}{z^{4}+z^{2}+1}$ using the limit definition?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I know $z_0$ is a simple pole so I just want to evaluate the limit $\lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z)$.

(The answer is $\frac{1}{12}(3 - i \sqrt{3})$ and I'm not getting it using the limit way. I got the answer using a different method.)

---

Also, I need to evaluate the residue at $z_1=\exp(2i\pi/3)$. Is there a way to tell quickly what the correct signs will be in this case: $\frac{1}{12}(\pm 3 \pm i\sqrt{3})$?

Comment: Are you prepared to use L'Hôpital's rule to evaluate the limit? It's a common strategy when evaluating residues of simple poles. It shows a pole at $w$ has residue $w/(4w^2+2)$; use $z_1=-z_0^\ast$.

Comment: @J.G. Oh, yes sure I'll use it. I guess I had just forgotten about L' Hopital's rule. But I don't get your second comment. $z_1$ and $z_0$ are not conjugate.

Comment: I've amended that.

Comment: @J.G. Am I doing something wrong because L'Hopital's rule is also an ugly mess, or is that unavoidable because the answer below is also very computationally expensive?

Comment: I'd have to see what you're doing to know why it's ugly. You should just get$$\frac{z^3-wz^2}{z^4+z^2+1}\sim\frac{3z^2-2wz}{4z^3+2z}\to\frac{w}{4w^2+2}.$$

Comment: @J.G.: Thanks so much for commenting back. I was doing something stupid and your reply helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $\require{cancel}z\in\Bbb C$, $z^3-1=(z-1)\left(z^2+z+1\right)$, and therefore $z^6-1=\left(z^2-1\right)\left(z^4+z^2+1\right)$. So, since the roots of $z^6-1$ are $\pm1,\pm e^{\pi i/3}$, and $\pm e^{2\pi i/3}$ and the roots of $z^2-1$ are $\pm1$, the roots of $z^4+z^2+1$ are $\pm e^{\pi i/3}$ and $\pm e^{2\pi i/3}$, and therefore$$z^4+z^2+1=\left(z-e^{\pi i/3}\right)\left(z+e^{\pi i/3}\right)\left(z-e^{2\pi i/3}\right)\left(z+e^{2\pi i/3}\right).$$So\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=e^{\pi i/3}}\frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}&=\lim_{z\to e^{\pi i/3}}\frac{\cancel{\left(z-e^{\pi i/3}\right)}z^2}{\cancel{\left(z-e^{\pi i/3}\right)}\left(z+e^{\pi i/3}\right)\left(z-e^{2\pi i/3}\right)\left(z+e^{2\pi i/3}\right)}\\&=\lim_{z\to e^{\pi i/3}}\frac{z^2}{\left(z+e^{\pi i/3}\right)\left(z-e^{2\pi i/3}\right)\left(z+e^{2\pi i/3}\right)}\\&=\frac{e^{2\pi i/3}}{2e^{\pi i/3}\left(e^{\pi i/3}-e^{2\pi i/3}\right)\left(e^{\pi i/3}+e^{2\pi i/3}\right)}\\&=\frac{e^{\pi i/3}}{2\left(e^{\pi i/3}-e^{2\pi i/3}\right)\left(e^{\pi i/3}+e^{2\pi i/3}\right)}\\&=\frac{e^{\pi i/3}}{2\left(e^{2\pi i/3}-e^{4\pi i/3}\right)}\\&=\frac1{2\left(e^{\pi i/3}-e^{3\pi i/3}\right)}\\&=\frac1{2\left(e^{\pi i/3}+1\right)}\text{ (since $e^{3\pi i/3}=e^{\pi i}=-1$)}\\&=\frac1{3+\sqrt 3\,i}\\&=\frac{3-\sqrt3\,i}{12}.\end{align}

---

Here is another approach. Let $p(z)=z^4+z^2+1$. Then:\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=e^{\pi i/3}}\frac{z^2}{z^4+z^2+1}&=\lim_{z\to e^{\pi i/3}}\left(z-e^{\pi i/3}\right)\frac{z^2}{p(z)}\\&=\lim_{z\to e^{\pi i/3}}\frac{z^2}{\frac{p(z)-p\left(e^{\pi i/3}\right)}{z-e^{\pi i/3}}}\\&=\frac{e^{2\pi i/3}}{p'\left(e^{\pi i/3}\right)}\\&=\frac{e^{2\pi i/3}}{4\left(e^{\pi i/3}\right)^3+2e^{\pi i/3}}\\&=\frac{e^{2\pi i/3}}{-4+2e^{\pi i/3}}\\&=\frac{-\frac12+\frac{\sqrt3}2i}{-3+\sqrt3\,i}\\&=\frac{3-\sqrt3\,i}{12}.\end{align}